# routing to a named outlet from named outlet - Angular4

Tags: angular, router

I'm currently creating an Angular4 app, which is an UI for an online game. As one feature of this app, there is a phone, which consist in one primary router outlet and one auxiliary router outlet who is in charged of displaying some hints. Thanks to the use of named outlet, the user can navigate on the main route while the auxiliary route is still displayed.

As a stand-alone, the phone feature works great.
**The whole app's structure is the following:**

```
## root.component.html ##
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="phone"><router-outlet> // will load phone.component
<router-outlet name="other-feature-1"><router-outlet> // will load feature.component
```

**The whole app's routes are:**

```
## routes.module.ts ##
const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: PhoneComponent,
        outlet: 'phone',
        children: [
            {
                ... non-outlet children
            },
            {
                path: '',
                component: HintComponent,
                outlet: 'hint'
                children: [
                    ...
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: FeatureComponent,
        outlet: 'other-feature',
        children: [
        ...
        ]
    }
];
```

**phone component's content:**

```
## phone.component.html ##
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
<router-outlet name='hint'><router-outlet>
<div>...graphic content..</div>
```

The main idea is that each feature has its own router-outlet so that we can, if needed, display some features at the same time.

But I didn't succeed to integrate this feature in the whole UI as I'm not able to populate the named router outlets inside the phone feature, which now contains a primary outlets and some auxiliary outlets.

**the problem is**:
How can i populate an auxiliary router outlet from an auxiliary outlet ?

Here is an abstract plunk of the situation.
Only represents a *single feature branch* (for example `<router-outlet name="phone"><router-outlet>`):
http://plnkr.co/edit/o0DFop?p=preview

I managed to navigate from parent named outlet to child primary outlet (with `this.router.navigate([{outlets: {'phone': 'non-outlet-path'}}])` but not from parent named-outlet to child named-outlet.
*Please look at the plunk given above.*

Thanks.

Comment: why is your path empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your outlet names are just mismatched, on line 66 in plunkr app.ts:

```
<router-outlet name="aux-nested"></router-outlet>
```

should be:

```
<router-outlet name="nested"></router-outlet>
```

so that it matches the outlet name in route config (line 95) and the routerlink outlet name (line 61).

Comment: Ow what a stupid mistake. Thanks for that quick answer.